# Binding a slider to an input field dynamically

Tags: jquery, maps

I have an input field that controls a value for a google maps div, which has a circle in it, and I want to change its value (and of course the radius of the circle) with a slider in real time. The circle size only changes when I add orr rewrite the value of the field, it changes when the slider moves, but the circle does not change.

The slider and the field:

```
$(function () {
    $("#radius-range-min").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 500,
        min: 1,
        max: 10000,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#us3-radius").val(ui.value).focus();
        }
    });
    $("#us3-radius").val("" + $("#radius-range-min").slider("value"));
```

And the .js file call:

```
$('#us3').locationpicker({

    location: {latitude: lat, longitude: lon},
    radius: 500,
    zoom: 16,
    inputBinding: {
        //latitudeInput: $('#us3-lat'),
        //longitudeInput: $('#us3-lon'),
        radiusInput: $("#us3-radius")//,
        //locationNameInput: $('#us3-address')
    },
    enableAutocomplete: true,
    onchanged: function (currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
        // Uncomment line below to show alert on each Location Changed event
        //alert("Location changed. New location (" + currentLocation.latitude + ", " + currentLocation.longitude + ")");
    }
});
});});
```

How can I bind the slider to the circle radius?

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: Sorry, the boss forbid it.

Comment: No problem, I tested it locally, see my answer. **Edit: now**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#map").locationpicker({
        radius: 1
    });
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 10000,
        slide: function(){
            $("#map").locationpicker({
                radius: $(this).slider("value")
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So for your case that would be:

```
$("#radius-range-min").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 500,
    min: 1,
    max: 10000,
    slide: function () {
        $("#us3").locationpicker({
            radius: $(this).slider("value")
        });
    }
});
```

**Make sure to define locationpicker() BEFORE the slider, otherwise it won't work.**